# Блокируется UI при работе с другим окном

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Переделал код под async await, и всё работает замечательно, до тех пор, пока не начинаю работать с другим окном. В этом случае UI главного окна блокируется.

Записал видео-вопросом - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2T_rnYsYWs

Собственно, вопрос из видео: как выполнять работу в разных UI независимо?

P.S. пробовал через код-помощник

```
static class AsyncHelper {
    static public ThreadPoolRedirector RedirectToThreadPool() =>
        new ThreadPoolRedirector();
}

public struct ThreadPoolRedirector : INotifyCompletion {
    // awaiter и awaitable в одном флаконе
    public ThreadPoolRedirector GetAwaiter() => this;

    // true означает выполнять продолжение немедленно 
    public bool IsCompleted => Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) =>
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => continuation());

    public void GetResult() { }
}
```

пробовал через

```
await Task.Run(()=>{
...
});
```

но результат тот же.

Код из видео:

1.

```
var updateThread = new Thread(async () => await UpdateAsync());
updateThread.Start();
```

2.

```
public async Task UpdateAsync() {
        //await AsyncHelper.RedirectToThreadPool();

        while (true) {
            string response = await ircClient.fetchServerMessage();
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.Contains("PRIVMSG")) {
                    ChatMessageArgs chatMessage = await stripChatMessageAsync(response);
                    if (ignoreList.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(chatMessage.name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1) continue;
                    OnChatReceived?.Invoke(this, chatMessage);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

3.

```
private async void ChatMessageReceived(Bot bot, ChatMessageArgs chatMessage) {          
    noticePanel.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { noticePanel.chatNoticeNew(chatMessage); });
}
```

4.

```
public void chatNoticeNew(ChatMessageArgs chatMessage) {
        while (noticeList.Count < 10) {
            ChatNoticeWFR newNotice = new ChatNoticeWFR();
            noticeList.Add(newNotice);
        }

        ChatNoticeWFR notice = noticeList[0];

        noticeList.RemoveAt(0);
        noticeList.Insert(noticeList.Count, notice);

        _stackPanel.Children.Remove(notice);
        _stackPanel.Children.Insert(0, notice);
    }
```

Comment: Независимо от того. сколько у вас окон, все UI-сообщения поступают в одну очередь сообщений. Насколько я понимаю, у вас переполняется эта очередь, т. е. сообщений слишком много. Человек все равно не может распознать десятки изменений значений в секунду, поэтому тем или иным способом ограничьте апдейт UI максимум несколько раз в секунду.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, проблема никак не в этом. Я подключился к множетсву каналов только что бы более наглядно показать проблему. Даже если приходит всего 1-2 сообщений в секунду, то возникают микроподвисания

Comment: @Bulson да хоспаде, причем тут вообще это? Я пишу интерфейс в отдельном проекте, что бы потом его подключить, а WinForms использовал просто ради примера.

Comment: Мне думается вам нужно завести буфер в виде [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) и туда отправлять все полученные сообщения. В UI же опрашивать эту очередь-буфер с некой периодичностью, допустим в полсекунды, еще можно поиграться количеством считываемых из буфера сообщений за раз для отображения в случае некот. торможения UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для коллекций используйте `ItemsControl`, в которой есть свой темплейт и биндите значения из модели на вьюху.

В дополнение, для разделения вьюх и их логики используют архитектурный паттерн MVVM.

Почитать:

- https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/
- https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php

---

Дополение:

`Update` у вас помечен модификатором `async`, соответственно, возвращайте `Task`.

Использование таски не гарантирует создание нового потока. Создавайте новый поток:

```
var updateThread = new Thread(async () => await UpdateAsync());
updateThread.Start();
```

Не забудьте сделать объект диспоузаблом и на диспоузе стопать этот поток: `updateThread.Abort();`

P.S. что делает у вас `stripChatMessageAsync()`? Помните, что вычисляемые операции оборачивать в таску не следует - это бесполезно.

Comment: Перевод в `Thread` результатов не дал. `stripChatMessageAsync()` просто разбивает сообщение в нужный мне формат, но он тут непричем. Если убрать создание сообщения на панели - главный UI работает без блокировок, соответственно проблема где-то в `noticePanel.chatNoticeNew(chatMessage)`. Код сейчас добавлю.

Comment: @Виталий `Dispatcher.Invoke()` выполняйте внутри метода `chatNoticeNew()` и только для той части когда, которая модифицирует данные вьюхи

Comment: @Виталий если предоставите ссылку на солюшн с минимальным воспроизводимым примером, я могу попробовать решить проблему.

Comment: Что-то подобное yadi.sk/d/uzWcZjAJsFQxcw

Comment: @Виталий Нет, не то. В этом примере вы прямо в `Dispatcher.Invoke()` запихнули `Thread.Sleep(100);`, поэтому тут форма и педалит.

Comment: Тогда только через дискорд/тимвивер, ибо создать минимальный пример = перекопировать половину кода. В любом случае спасибо за советы.

Comment: @Виталий вообще я бы вам советовал вместо добавления юзер контролов руками юзать солюшены получше. Например, с помощью `ItemsControl` https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/778150/WindowsFormsApp3.zip

Comment: С этого момента я перестаю понимать принципы работы интерфейсов, и, похоже, надеваю чёрную мантию и ухожу в монастырь. Мне просто показался Ваш способ удобным, я просто поменял `StackPanel` на `ItemsControl`, просто запустил прогу, и интерфейс просто не лагает, даже при 60 сообщений в секунду.

Comment: Эмм... Можете, наверное, оформить как ответ

Comment: @Виталий А что за вьюха `ChatNoticeWFR`? Много визуальных элементов?

Comment: Нет, её на видео видно. Сейчас я использую её же, но помещаю не в `StackPanel`, а в `ItemsControl`, и всё отлично.

Comment: @Виталий обновил ответ. Советую порефачить вашу аппу и применить приведенный паттерн, ибо у вас уже логика отображений и бизнес логика переплелась воедино